# Display string representing arithmetic calculation, rather than numerical output of the calculation

Tags: r, string

I have this grid-matrix:

```
cutoff <- c(pi/48, 2*pi/48, 3*pi/48, pi/12)
lambda <- c(5:10)
eta <- seq(1, 1.5, by=0.1)

grid <- expand.grid(cutoff, lambda, eta)
```

And this is the output I get after the function (which calculates the *sharpe* vector):

```
best_grid <- grid[max(sharpe),]

       cutoff  lambda  eta
[17] 0.1963495   5     1.5
```

But I would like to get this:

```
       cutoff  lambda  eta
[17]  3*pi/48    5     1.5
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: what you want is a string and therefore would need to be as the string class. If you later want to calculate from it you can probably write a line to decode the string into numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create separate string vector of cutoff values that correspond to the values in `cutoff` and then match to that. I just selected four random rows for illustration.

```
cutoff.string = c("pi/48", "2*pi/48", "3*pi/48", "pi/12")

best_grid = grid[c(1,20,50,120),]

best_grid$cutoff = cutoff.string[match(best_grid$cutoff, cutoff)]

best_grid
```

> ```
>    cutoff lambda eta
> 1   pi/48      5 1.0
> 2   pi/12      9 1.0
> 3 2*pi/48      5 1.2
> 4   pi/12     10 1.4
> ```

Or, with @HaddE.Nuff's suggestion:

```
cutoff = quote(c(pi/48, 2*pi/48, 3*pi/48, pi/12))

grid <- expand.grid(cutoff=eval(cutoff), lambda=lambda, eta=eta)

best_grid = grid[c(1,20,50,120),]

best_grid$cutoff = gsub(" ","", as.character(cutoff[-1]))[match(best_grid$cutoff, eval(cutoff))]
```

Comment: Or the best of both worlds with `cutoff <- quote(c(pi/48, 2*pi/48, 3*pi/48, pi/12)); eval(cutoff); as.character(cutoff[-1])`